# Good theory books/guitar/singing books?

Tags: guitar, theory, voice

These days I've had to start pushing myself to practice, and the more I practice the more I realize I'm lacking in theory.
There's just... So much to learn, that sometimes it can be overwelming. 
But you should never stop perusing knowledge, and the best type of things to learn are from other people!
So, my question is which books have you read that personally helped you with making theory make sense? 
What are some personal books you find helped you the most? Or perhaps you follow a YouTuber--
Who do you follow? And who inspires you?
Recommendation would much appreciated!
Thank you :)

Comment: [Questions seeking external resources are off-topic here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and so are questions where ['every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”'](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) Additionally, you cast a pretty broad net with "theory books/guitar/singing books." You can find book recommendations sprinkled throughout answers to specific questions around the site. Do some searching and I'm sure that you will find some stuff.

Comment: Go through amazon.com looking for theory or whatever interests you, compare reviews, and whip out the credit card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube is an awesome resource, and it is free.

Just take everything with a grain of salt.

I recommend any instructional videos by Rob Chapman and Paul Gilbert.
Both are intelligent and experienced stage performers.

Take your time with this learning process. 
It's a marathon, not a sprint. 
And nothing is going to make you a better guitar player, singer, and live performer like practice and live experience.

Hook up with local players who are better than you, but willing to spend some time passing on tips, tactics, tricks, and techniques.

You will always step up your game when you learn from people who care about sharing the goodness of music.

Comment: +1. Especially for your second sentence! Trouble is, for someone who *doesn't* know much, how will they sort the chaff from the grain?

Comment: I find some good sources of study in used book shops and reading questions and answers here. It's a very comfortable way for me to learn at my own pace.